# change sylius shop domain from locale based to country code based

Tags: symfony, subdomain, url-routing, locale, sylius

I want to change the sylius shop url from locale based to country code based.
Currently my url is **ja.product-local.com** which sets the locale to ja and currency to JPY.But now i want to remove the locale from url and want to add country code instead. i.e. jp.product-local.com.
Old routing is

```
  resource : "../../config/routing.yml"
  host: "{_locale}.{our_domain}"
  prefix: /
  requirements:
    _locale: ja|en
    our_domain: 'product-local.com'
    sub_domain: jp|en
  defaults:
    _locale: ja  #en
    our_domain: "product-local.com"
    sub_domain: 'jp'
```

So i have modified the syliusshop host parameter like this.

```
host: "{sub_domain}.{our_domain}"
```

But in this case i am not able to set locale and currency based on country code. Setting parameter in the request is not working.so where exactly i can set it u.Please help me out.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a guide to [disable localized URLs](https://docs.sylius.com/en/latest/cookbook/shop/disabling-localised-urls.html).

For setting the locale and currency based on the subdomain I can think of a few different options:

1. Use different channels with a single locale, currency and country.
2. Add a [request listener](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel.html#the-kernel-request-event) that will set the locale and the currency based on the subdomain, just like [Sylius already does for locale](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/src/Sylius/Bundle/LocaleBundle/Resources/config/services.xml#L51-L55).
3. Create add custom locale and currency contexts with higher priority to return values based on the subdomain.